# Translate error message of login form

Tags: symfony, translation

I use FOSUserBundle login form and i would like translate errors messages. These messages are launched here: **vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php**

```
protected function checkAuthentication(UserInterface $user, UsernamePasswordToken $token)
    {
        $currentUser = $token->getUser();
        if ($currentUser instanceof UserInterface) {
            if ($currentUser->getPassword() !== $user->getPassword()) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('The credentials were changed from another session.');
            }
        } else {
            if (!$presentedPassword = $token->getCredentials()) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password cannot be empty.');
            }

            if (!$this->encoderFactory->getEncoder($user)->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $presentedPassword, $user->getSalt())) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException('The presented password is invalid.');
            }
        }
    }
```

I've write **app/Resources/translations/validators.fr.yml**

```
"The presented password cannot be empty.":      "Veuillez saisir un mot de passe."
```

I've write **app/Resources/translations/messages.fr.yml**

```
"The presented password cannot be empty.":      "Veuillez saisir un mot de passe."
```

But it doesn't work.
Other translation are working (=>fr), but i've problem with these messages.

Special procedure for these messages ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In file Sonata/UserBundle/Resources/views/Admin/Security/login.html.twig You have:

```
<div class="alert-message error">{{ error|trans({}, 'SonataUserBundle') }}</div>
```

so You must change SonataUserBundle to whatever translation file You are using or add
src/Your/Bundle/Resources/translations/SonataUserBundle.{locale}.yml

and inside translation file:

```
'Bad credentials': 'Your translation'
'The presented password is invalid.': 'Your translation'
'The presented password cannot be empty.': 'Your translation'
```

I hope it's clear enough ;]

Comment: I've use a similar way: I catch the error, and display it in twig with trans.

Answer (score 2):

In version 1.3 of FOSUserBundle "Bad Credentials" it's actually "Bad Credentials." (mind the last dot).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.
You have to catch the error and do what you need to do...For example display a message with flash session message and redirect to your forget password page.

Comment: Yes, it's an idea, i will try it.

Comment: Identification is internal of FOSUserBundle :/ I can't catch

Comment: it's similar i think: catch error, and do with it something =)