# Symfony2 - How to translate "Bad credentials" login error message from FOSUserBundle ?

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'd like to customize the error message ('Bad credentials')if a there is a login error.
I do it but doesn't work.
This is the template login :

```
{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
{% endif %}<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="/account" />
<input type="submit" name="login" />
```

the file config.yml I have this :

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }
```

in parametre.yml I have this:

```
locale: en
```

I added the file in directory MyBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.ymy:

```
security:
login:
    username: "Username:"
    password: "Password:"
    submit: Login
    forgot_username: "Forgot username"
    forgot_password: "Forgot password"
    registration: register
    # Security
    "Bad credentials": "Your user name or password are incorrect."
```

but always I have the Bad credentials error message

Comment: possible duplicate of [Customize Authentication - Login Symfony2 Messages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201849/customize-authentication-login-symfony2-messages)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that error message has **dot(.)** at the end of the string.

You can correct this using the twig trim filter:

```
{{ error|trim('.')|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

Answer (score 4):

In my login form I have :

```
{# Error login form #}
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>{% trans %}login.error{% endtrans %}!</strong> {{ error.messageKey|trans({}, 'messages') }}
        </div>
{% endif %}
```

Here the 'messages' is important as it refers the domain of your translation, or if you prefer the name of your translation file. In my case : `messages.en.yml`

With the fosuserbundle 1.3.5 you have to put this in your message.yml

```
"Invalid credentials." : Bad email/password combination
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 2):

The `Bad Credentials` error isn't part of any parent group (`security.login` or domain).

To translate it you need to add the key/value pair to a regular `messages.<locale>.<format>` file, like so...

`Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml`

```
"Bad Credentials": Incorrect username and/or password

// Other stuff
acme_demo:
    form:
        cats: Cats
```

Just for reference...

This answer (pretty much) can be found in any of the following:

[Customize Authentication - Login Symfony2 Messages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9201849/1791606)

[Recommended way of translating authentication errors in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8869645/1791606)

[Translate error message of login form](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8564899/1791606)

Comment: **Your answer is not correct**. `FOSUserBundle` is the default translation domain for the template that renders the form ... set via **[`trans_default_domain`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig#L3)** which is applied to `error | trans` -> **[here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig#L7)** ...

Comment: That is correct, kind of. If you are extending the base FOSUserBundle template then the domain is (as @nifr correctly stated) `FOSUserBundle`, otherwise it will just be message (or what ever you have set if you have set otherwise).

Comment: Jeah that's it basically - the [question_]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201849/customize-authentication-login-symfony2-messages) you referred to overrides/explicitly sets the translation domain to `messages` ... which i'd say isn't quite the best solution if you want to keep your translations well organized... which is the purpose of domains actually :)

Comment: anyways +1 for the link collection :) Should definitely be helpful for others seeking help with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong **translation domain**.

FOSUserBundle uses `FOSUserBundle` instead of `messages`. Have a look at the default **[template](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig#L3)**.

Translation files inside bundles are stored at:

```
<bundle>/Resources/translations/<translationDomain>.<locale>.<format>
```

**solution:**

Rename the translation file to `FOSUserBundle.<locale>.<format>`. Afterwards clear your cache to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code wroted in MyBundle/Resources/translations/messages.en.yml  like this;

```
Bad credentials.: "Invalid user/password"
```

Not: Not use under `login:` write it directly

Answer (score 0):

just information I do not use FosUserBundle and I follow every step but the same message error Bad credentials

Answer (score 0):

you need to like:

```
<div>{{ error|trans }}</div>
```

instead of:

```
<div>{{ error.message|trans }}</div>
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The message "Bad Credentials" misses a dot.
It might be "Bad Credentials."

You can override translation file with the translation of this line only under your bundle

Don't forget to add translation domain

```
{{ error|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}
```

or globally

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
```

Note : this solution tested with FOSuserBundle as the person hwo ask say he is not using it.